# For a nonnegative random variable X with CDF, the expected value

Tags: probability-theory

For a nonnegative random variable X with CDF,  the expected value is given by

$$
E\left[ X \right] =\int _{ 0 }^{ \infty  }{ P\left[ X>x \right] dx=\int _{ 0 }^{ \infty  }{ \left[ 1-{ F }_{ X }\left( x \right)  \right] dx }  } 
$$

Proof.

$$
\int _{ 0 }^{ \infty  }{ P\left[ X>x \right] dx=\int _{ 0 }^{ \infty  }{ \int _{ x }^{ \infty  }{ { f }_{ X }\left( u \right) dudx } =\int _{ 0 }^{ \infty  }{ \left\{ \int _{ 0 }^{ u }{ dx }  \right\} { f }_{ X }\left( u \right) du=\int _{ 0 }^{ \infty  }{ u{ f }_{ X }\left( u \right) du }  }  }  } 
$$

$$
I \quad can't\quad  understand\quad  this\quad  transformation ;\left\{ \int _{ 0 }^{ u }{ dx }  \right\}
$$

Comment: Note that $$\int _{ 0 }^{ \infty  }\!\!\!\int _{ x }^{ \infty  }{ { f }_{ X }(u) dudx } =\int _{ 0 }^{ \infty  }\!\!\! \int _{ 0 }^{ \infty  }\mathbf 1_{u>x}\,{ { f }_{ X }(u) dudx } =\int _{ 0 }^{ \infty  }\!\!\! \left\{ \int _{ 0 }^{ \infty }{\mathbf 1_{x<u} dx }  \right\} { f }_{ X }(u) du$$ hence $$\int _{ 0 }^{ \infty  }\!\!\!\int _{ x }^{ \infty  }{ { f }_{ X }(u) dudx } =\int _{ 0 }^{ \infty  }\!\! \!\left\{ \int _{ 0 }^{ u }{dx }  \right\} { f }_{ X }(u) du.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fubini's theorem is used to change the order of integration from first the integral over $u$ and then the integral over $x$ to first the integral over $x$ and then over $u$.